# Can not upgrade ubuntu 18.10 to higher version

Tags: ubuntu

I can not upgrade ubuntu from 18.10 to newer version. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it said `does not have a Release file` thus I can not run `sudo apt-get upgrade`

[image: bug apt-get update]
Is there any way I can upgrade my ubuntu to a newer version?

[image: Bug update-manager]
I have tried `sudo do-release-upgrade` but it is said that `An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to askubuntu

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release and https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ubuntu 18.10 has been end of life since 18th July 2019.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life)  It looks like they have now removed it (`cosmic`) completely from the apt repository.

You can still get Ubuntu 18.10 packages if you change your apt sources (/etc/apt/sources.list) to point to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.  **Note that these are not maintained and no security fixes will be applied.**

A much better alternative, if you can, is to upgrade your system to a later version (eg: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).  There's an official tutorial on [how to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today).

The technique used should also apply to upgrading from 18.10, however please note that you may not be able to upgrade directly from 18.10 to 20.04.  This may require multiple "hops"; meaning upgrading via another version or two to get all the way to 20.04.

---

In your screenshot, the repository that's failing is a PPA. You don't need to upgrade these before system upgrade.  They are usually registered in a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

I recommend finding which one and just comment out every `deb` line in that file. You are looking for `ubuntu-vn`. Then you can put it back to normal after.

*When you have upgraded*, remember to check your PPAs point to the correct release.  They should say `focal` not `cosmic`.

Comment: Thank you but https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today didnt work for my case

Comment: The `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` requires to install all available updates before upgrade but I can not run `sudo apt-get update`. Actually I have tried `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` before I posted this

Comment: yes I tried but it didnt work also

Comment: sorry I really want to give you something but in this comment I can not add any pictures. If possible, can I chat with you somewhere? on Slack?

Comment: I just add a picture on my post, can you have a look?

Comment: @tam edited. Looks like you can just temporarily remove that repo.

Comment: @Philip the page you linked describes LTS-to-LTS upgrades; AFAIR upgrades from an EOL non-LTS are more complicated.

Comment: @PhilipCouling thank to you I fixed the `sudo apt-get update`, then I run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` but it said `An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool. `

Comment: @PhilipCouling I also tried `update-manager` but it also said that `An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.`

Comment: @PhilipCouling I update a new screenshot, please have a look

Comment: @PhilipCouling I can upgrade to new version. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @Philip exactly that, requiring multiple hops. But it seems Tam figured out how to upgrade anyway.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. Edited for future readers.

Comment: @Philip the OP posted [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590574/86440) with a link to the detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be done but it's somewhat tricky. Many users prefer to backup their entire home directory, make a clean new install and then restore the home directory from the backup. But there is a (hopefully) working recipe on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227967/upgrade-from-18-10-to-20-04-options)

Answer (score 0):

To fix `An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.`, I followed this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208109/how-to-upgrade-from-18-10-to-19-10-using-the-command-line